# Not able to authenticate and insert into the mongo DB . pymongo- python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, docker-compose, pymongo

The docker compose yml file has the mongo container settings as shown below:

```
         mongo:
            image: mongo
            restart: always
            ports:
              - 27017:27017
            environment:
              MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "minu"
              MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "strongPq23$"
```

I have a python code that looks like below:

```
        import pymongo
        import sys

        class mongo_client:

            def __init__(self,host,port,db,username,password):
                self.client =pymongo.MongoClient(host=host,port=port,username=username,password=password,authSource=db)
                self.mydb = self.client[db]


            def insert_one(self,json,collection):
                try:
                    inserted=(self.mydb[collection]).insert_one(json)
                except:
                    print("Unexpected error while inserting into Mongo DB:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                    return
                return inserted.inserted_id

        m=mongo_client(host='127.0.0.1',port=27017,db=0,username='minu',password="strongPq23$",authSource=0
        m.insert_one(some_dict,collection)
```

I am not sure if the authentication method I do is correct? I get authentication error. I just want to insert docs using insert_one() which works otherwise if there is no container and no user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a seperate user to the root user to use in your pymongo code. You will need to have access to the mongo command line tool to do this. Assuming a linux client you can run:

```
SERVER=localhost
PORT=27017
ROOT_USERNAME=root
ROOT_PASSWORD=very_strong_root_password
ADMIN_USERNAME=minu
ADMIN_PASSWORD=strongPq23$

docker run -d -p ${PORT}:27017 --name mongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${ROOT_USERNAME} -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ROOT_PASSWORD} --restart always mongo
mongo mongodb://${ROOT_USERNAME}:${ROOT_PASSWORD}@${SERVER}:${PORT}/admin?authSource=admin --eval "db.createUser({user: '${ADMIN_USERNAME}', pwd: '${ADMIN_PASSWORD}', roles: [{role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin'}]});"
mongo mongodb://${ROOT_USERNAME}:${ROOT_PASSWORD}@${SERVER}:${PORT}/admin?authSource=admin --eval "db.updateUser('${ADMIN_USERNAME}', {roles: [{role: 'root', db: 'admin'}]});"
```

Then in python run this is a test:

```
import pymongo
import sys

class MyMongoClient:

    def __init__(self,connection_string):
        self.client =pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string)
        self.mydb = self.client.db


    def insert_one(self, json, collection):
        try:
            inserted = self.mydb[collection].insert_one(json)
        except:
            print("Unexpected error while inserting into Mongo DB:", sys.exc_info()[0:2])
            return
        return inserted.inserted_id


m = MyMongoClient(connection_string='mongodb://minu:strongPq23$@localhost:27017/your_database?authSource=admin')
print(m.insert_one({'a': 1}, 'test_collection'))
```

Note this does give ADMIN_USERNAME very broad permissions so you can tailor these as required. Also, once you have this working. mount a volume on you docker container otherwise all the data will vanish on each restart.

Comment: I already have ROOT_USER in docker_compose. why do i need ADMIN_USER. My question is given the root user created while containerization, how to authenticate while creating a py mongo client in the code. With the same docker-compose i tried m = MyMongoClient(connection_string='mongodb://minu:strongPq23$@localhost:27017/your_database?authSource=admin') . But this did not work.While  at insert_one() it times out

Comment: What I have outlined is the correct way to set up the authentication required for MongoDB for use with pymongo. If you want to continue to try and use the wrong approach and continue to be surprised when it doesn't work, then that is up to you.